# Slim skeleton not responding to any new routes other than root

Tags: php, rest, jwt, slim

I am very new to slim framework so below is the exact steps I did in the /varr/www/html for apace on centos 7 with php7.
1. composer create-project slim/slim-skeleton
2. rename is to apiv1
3. chown -R apache:apache apiv1
4. Then in /src/middleware.php I added this .

```
$app->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
    $response = $next($req, $res);
    return $response
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
});
```

5. Then in the src/route.php-

```
use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;
$app->get('/', function()  {
   // $app->response->setStatus(200);
    echo "Welcome to Slim based API";
});
$app->get('/rest', function()  {
   // $app->response->setStatus(200);
    echo "Welcome to Rest page";
});
```

The issue now I got to my http://myip/apiv1/public it show me the echo "Welcome to Slim based API"; but when I type http://myip/apiv1/public/rest I get this message not found The requested URL /apiv1/public/rest was not found on this server. What could be wrong in my settings?

Comment: Is it `apiv2` or `apiv1`?

Comment: Sorry  myy mistake it should apiv1. What couldd be issue to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a web application, it is important to distinguish between the public and non-public areas. The folder `public` serves your application and will therefore also be directly accessible by all browsers, search engines and API clients. To fix this routing issue just define the `public` directory in Apache as `DocumentRoot`. [More details](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#documentroot).

The correct URL should then look like this:

- http://myip/apiv1
- http://myip/apiv1/rest

Comment: The problem  now I have used this method <Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
    Options -Indexes
</Directory> it seems still not working

Comment: I am very lost been trying for many hours I cant find on how to set this virtual host settings

Comment: Actually which is the correct method to install this slim is the pure slim or slim-skeleton

Comment: Do you have a `.htaccess` and a front controller? Maybe try this [slim-skeleton](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton) or read my [slim tutorial](https://gist.github.com/odan/d2b889c350aa2ea0ff8e5ca93ce588a2) (optimized for slim and apache)

Comment: Yes I have tried both slim-skeleton and just pure slim only. I .htaccess on default in the public folder for slim-skeleton. I know is a pure url rewrite issue been trying all sorts of suggestion the web it does not work/

Comment: I have edited to httpd.conf for the allowoverride to be all. What else am I missing very lost here?